# How to use pip with python 2 & 3 installed? (OSX)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pipenv

I am trying to get python 3 working on my OSX laptop.

I need to install requests for python 3, and it isn't working.

I think I've managed to get pip installed for both python 2.7 & python 3 however...

Whenever I use 'pip' it points to python2... I can't seem to access the pip for python 3?

Comment: You have `pip` and `pip3` for Python-2.x and Python-3.x respectively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In all likelihood, `pip3` will be installed pointing to your Python 3 installation, so your use case is probably solvable by just switching from:

```
$ pip install foo
```

to:

```
$ pip3 install foo  # Or pip3.7 install foo if you need to disambiguate further
```

That said, it can get kind of complicated when you have many different Python installs, where `pip`/`pip3` might have been installed pointing to a Python version that doesn't correspond to the `python`/`python3` you're using, which can be quite confusing.

If you know `python` & `python3` are the correct executable, just use it to invoke `pip` on your behalf. It's fairly easy too, just check your version to be sure it's the one you expect (e.g. on my system):

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.15rc1
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.6
```

then use the appropriate one with `-mpip`, a flag to run an installed module/package via the chosen Python as the "main" executable, bypassing the need for specifically versioned `pip` executable entirely. So if you wanted to install `foo` for Python 3.6 on my machine, you'd run:

```
$ python3 -mpip install foo
```

This is especially useful on Windows, where the `pip` executables often either don't exist, or are not installed in the `PATH`, so it's irritating to use them. Instead, use the [Windows launcher](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) that comes with any modern Python 3 version (but manages all Python versions on the machine), and is used to disambiguate among various versions. For example:

```
C:\>; Installs foo for latest installed version of Python 3
C:\>py -3 -mpip install foo
C:\>; Installs foo for latest installed version of Python 2
C:\>py -2 -mpip install foo
C:\>; Installs foo for latest installed version of Python 3.6
C:\>py -3.6 -mpip install foo
```

Essentially, any use of `pip` can be replaced by executing the Python interpreter directly with the `-mpip` option to run the `pip` package as the "main" executable.

This trick applies to many other tools with dedicated launchers that are often not installed in the `PATH`, particularly on Windows, and it makes updates easier too; my Windows shortcut for launching `ipython3` never used a hardcoded path to the launcher (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\ipython3.exe`), instead using `%WINDIR%\py.exe -3 -mIPython`. In addition to being more portable (the shortcut "just works" on any Windows system with a semi-recent Python 3 install), it's self-updating; when I upgraded from 3.6 to 3.7, the shortcut didn't have to change at all (I had to run `py -3 -mpip install ipython` again to get IPython reinstalled, but once I'd done that, the shortcut seamlessly began referring to the 3.7 install with no changes needed).

Answer (score 1):

Run this command to find the python that is used before running pip: `which python`. You can do the same idea to find which pip version is being run: `which pip`

You’ll need to create separate virtual environments in order to use different python versions and/or python dependencies. Use something like conda or venv to do this. Then, ensure that the desired python version virtual environment is activated prior to installing a new package with pip.

Answer (score 1):

To install `requests` for `python3`, use `pip3 install requests` which is the `pip` installer for Python 3 modules.

This guide has some further info on getting Python 3 working on a mac.
https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/

Answer (score -2):

try to `sudo apt-get update` first then `sudo apt-get install python3-pip --fix-missing`

Comment: There is no `apt` on OS X.